# Find the point spectrum

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $x$ and $y$ be nonzero vectors in a Hilbert Space $H$. Let $f(z) = \langle z, x \rangle y$. Find the point spectrum of $f$.

I know that $\lambda$ is in the point spectrum if $f(z)=\lambda z$ for a nonzero $z$. So, $\langle z, x\rangle y = \lambda z$. I'm not sure where to go from there though.

Comment: Subtract both sides from each other, you have $\lambda z - \langle z, x \rangle y = 0$. When can this be satisfied?

Comment: @s.harp I'm not really sure what you're leading at with that statement.

Comment: @s.harp would normalizing both sides be a start?

Comment: You can try to start like this also, what dimension does the image of $f$ have?

Comment: @s.harp would it be the same as the dimension of H since f maps a vector to a vector in the same Hilbert space?

Comment: No, it will not have the same dimension as $H$. You can see that every vector in the image is proportional to $y$. So the image (although it is a subspace of $H$) is one dimensional. If you want to find an eigenvector of $f$, you must solve $\lambda z = f(z)$. You know that everything in the image of $f$ is proportional to $y$, so what can you find out about a possible eigenvector $z$?

Comment: @s.harp so, z is linearly independent of y. I think this would yield a dependence only on x and y for $\lambda$. if we take $\lambda = <x,y>$ then would this equality be satisfied?

Comment: What makes you think an eigenvector should be linearly **independent** of $y$?

Comment: @s.harp z is only mapped into the scalar in the field that's attached to a fixed g so I figured linear independence

Comment: $z$ and $y$ are linearly independent $\iff$ there exist **no** constants $a,b  \in \mathbb F$ not both $0$ so that $a z + b y = 0$ is fulfilled. However the condition for $z$ to be an eigenvector is that there exists a $\lambda$ so that $\lambda z - \langle z,x\rangle y = 0$. Note that $\langle z, x \rangle$ is an element of the field. This is not compatible with linear independence.

Comment: @s.harp ok. I have no idea then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume here that your scalar product is anti-linear in the first argument and linear in the second, which is the usual convention. This means that $\langle \alpha v, \beta w \rangle = \overline\alpha \beta \langle v,w\rangle$ for all $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb C$. Note that this means that your map is not a linear map but an anti-linear map.

You are looking for a $z \in H$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb C$ so that $\lambda z = f(z)=\langle z ,x \rangle\, y$. Clearly $f(z)$ is always proportional to $y$. So if $\lambda \neq 0$ the equation is $z = \frac{\langle z, x \rangle}{\lambda} y$, and $z$ must be proportional to $y$.

Every vector proportional to $y$ is of the form $\alpha\, y$ for some $\alpha \in \mathbb C$, so the equation is just $f(\alpha\, y)=\langle \alpha \, y, x\rangle y= \lambda \alpha \, y$, or $(\overline\alpha \langle y,x\rangle - \alpha \lambda)y = 0$. If $y\neq0$ you must have $\overline{\alpha}\langle y ,x \rangle = \alpha \lambda$ or $\lambda = \frac{\overline \alpha}{\alpha}\langle y, x\rangle$. Indeed whenever $z=\alpha \, y$ then $z$ is an eigenvector of $f$ with eigenvalue $\frac{\overline \alpha}{\alpha}\langle y, x\rangle$.

What remains are the eigenvectors of eigenvalue $0$. This means that $f(z)=0$, but $z$ itself is not $0$. So you get $0=\langle z, x \rangle y$. This is satisfied by all vectors that are orthogonal to $x$, as then $\langle z, x\rangle = 0$. Whenever the Hilbert space is more than two dimensional to any vector you will always find orthogonal vectors.

So to summarise, the spectrum is $\left\{\frac{\overline \alpha}{\alpha}\langle y, x\rangle \mid \alpha \in \mathbb C, \alpha \neq0\right\}\cup\{0\}$ (unless $H$ is 1 dimensional).